# passing data to webform method using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatables

this is my ManageCategory.js

```
function SaveArea() {
    debugger;
    if (flag_Area == 0) {
         Temp = {
            'Category_id': $("#txtAddArea_Id").val(),
            'Category_name': $("#txtAddArea_Name").val().substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + $("#txtAddArea_Name").val().substr(1).toLowerCase()

        };



$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/InsertCategory",
            dataType: "json",
           // data: {},
            data: JSON.stringify(Temp),
            // data: JSON.stringify(contact, memberfilter, "\t"),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            //processData: true,
            success: function (Data) {
                alert(Data);
                //AreaList = Data;
                if (Data == "true") {
                    oTable_Area.fnClearTable();
                    GetArea();
                    jsonParse = JSON.parse(AreaList.d);
                    oTable_Area.fnAddData(jsonParse);
                    jNSuccessMsg("New Category is added in database successfully.");
                }
                else if (Data == "false") {
                    jNErrorMsg("Attention", "Category is already exist in the database");
                }
                else {
                    jNErrorMsg("Error In Add Category", Data);
                }
            }

        });
       // debugger;
        Id_Area = null;


    }
```

this is my WebForm1.aspx.cs

---

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string InsertCategory(string data)
        {
            IService1 wcfclient = ServiceHelper.InitService<IService1>();
            clsCategoryBLL obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<clsCategoryBLL>(data);
            bool flag = false;
            flag = wcfclient.InsertCategory(obj);
            return (flag.ToString());
        }
```

i am not able to add data in jquery datatables. $.ajax is not properly passing data to InsertCategory(web form method).

where am i going wrong ?plz help me out...
tnx in advance

Comment: If you do not know that you can debug it, how can we ? What error did you take ? and in witch point/line of code is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters in your InsertCategory pagemethod should match the posted JSON object.
In order to make your code work with the Temp JSON object , please change the InsertCategory pagemethod to the following  ( param names are case sensitive )

```
[WebMethod]
public static string InsertCategory(integer Category_id, string Category_name ){

// ...implementation...

}
```

You also don't need to use JSON.stringify for the data parameter in $.ajax, jQuery needs to transform the data to a query string, so it's better if you just pass the object it self.

You might wanna check out these blog posts for more info on working with asp.net pagemethods and jquery.

- http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/
- http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/